# Why is one user's profile page throwing an error?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Just go to [the activity tab in Servy's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/186381/servy?tab=activity), or any other tab.

This is what I see:

> [image]

The thing is, all the other profiles work fine. It seems to be a bug in Servy's page only (And the only working part of his profile page is [his "profile tab"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/186381/servy?tab=profile)).

Comment: It doesn't even work for me.  And it's not just the activity tab, but any part of the profile.

Comment: reproed by 3 others in chat.

Comment: Also, as flattering as it is, there really doesn't need to be a [meta-tag:servy] tag.

Comment: Repro-ed in IE11, FF and Chrome so it is not a browser thingy

Comment: @Servy http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3138762#3138762

Comment: The profile can't handle His awesomeness

Comment: Which 5xx code is Internal Servy Error, again?

Comment: @Air This is an External Servy Error.  I'm functioning fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There was a missing check on the newest badge that would cause the page to throw an exception for certain badges (namely - tag badges).

Servy just got another badge which isn't a tag badge, so that page no longer errors...

But I have fixed the code path and am pushing the fix soon.

Comment: This was quite fast :D don't forget [status-completed].